# Writing errors to the EventLog in WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, vsewss

How do you write to the event log in WSS 3.0? Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventLog.WriteEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hse04t8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but be aware that you probably need to run it inside a [RunWithElevatedPriviledges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in order to have sufficient rights